# Error "403 Forbidden" on Sharepoint Search Settings Page

Tags: sharepoint

Hello I thought I had solved this nightmare by re-entering the values in my SSP properties set up, however accessing the Search Settings page error has reared it ugly head again. Now all solutions point to this method listed here

```
* http://www.routtlogics.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=6
* http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadmin/thread/f00651cd-e452-45b9-b19e-90e89c3c3ad4
* http://blogs.technet.com/sushrao/archive/2009/03/26/microsoft-office-sharepoint-server-2007-moss-403-forbidden-error-when-clicked-on-search-settings-page.aspx
```

The above workaround(s) basically states that granting the local group WSS_WPG read and write permission to the Task folder in the Windows directory would solve the problem, however whenever I try to change to the permission attribute of this folder I get an access denied message, even when logged in as a Domain administrator, Enterprise and even the SharePoint Farm administrator.

Please guys how do I get around this access denied issue.

Thanks

Comment: Are you accessing the various sites on a browser running on a Sharepoint Web Front end server?  Try accessing from a completely different client machine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you the owner of the folder? Open the folder properties and select the Security tab. Click on the Advanced button and select the Owner tab. See what user is listed as the current owner.

Dave

Comment: Hi Dave, the current owner(s) is the Administrators group.

Comment: If it is the local administrator group (COMPUTERNAME\Administrators), you should verify that your domain admin account is a member of that group. It usually is, however you should still verify.
You can check this in Computer Management - Local Users and Groups - Groups and then open the properties of the Administrators group. You should see a few entries in this group like "Administrator" (local) and "DOMAIN\Domain Admins". If Domain Admins isn't in this group, add it in and retry the permissions. 

Dave